# Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Component'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, type-conversion, components

I have some code that makes a custom UI class. This is done in the following way:

```
public class EasyUIData
{
    protected static Canvas EasyCanvasOptions;
    protected static Vector2 EasyCanvasDimensions;
}

public class UIBaseProperties : EasyUIData
{
    protected GameObject UIElement;
    protected RectTransform Anchor;
    protected Vector2 Loc;
    protected int? SizeX, SizeY;

    public UIBaseProperties(Vector2 loc, int? sizeX = null, int? sizeY = null)
    {
        UIElement = new GameObject();
        this.Loc = loc;
        this.SizeX = sizeX;
        this.SizeY = sizeY;
    }
}

public class RawImage : UIBaseProperties
{
    private RawImage UIImageComponent;
    private Texture2D Img;

    public RawImage(Texture2D img, Vector2 loc, int? sizeX = null, int? sizeY = null) : base(loc, sizeX, sizeY)
    {
        UIImageComponent = UIElement.AddComponent(typeof(RawImage)) as RawImage; // this generates the error.
    }
}
```

But in the line where i want to add the `RawImage` component i get the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.Component' to 'Easy.UI.RawImage' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

I am not sure why because i used this technique once before and it worked just fine.
If something is unclear pls let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: What does EasyUIData inherit? I see no reason that object would be able to cast correctly into UnityEngine.Component

Comment: What kind of RawImage do you want to use? Unity already knows a component of the name RawImage. And you have build your own class with the same name. Maybe there is the confusion between yours and UnityEngine.UI.RawImage in your class.

Comment: @Eliasar The EasyUIData class doesnt inherit anything it is just the base. I will update my question for clarity

Comment: @GameGenerator I am making a custom UI framework that is build on top of the UI elements from unity. So i am trying to use the Component RawImage in this custom UI class.

Comment: @FutureCake Unity maybe dont know what Raw Image to use. You want UnityEngine.UI.RawImage but Unity understands Easy.UI.RawImage which seems to be no component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you named your script `RawImage`. It's generally not a good idea to name your script the-same name as Unity's component.

If your goal is to use Unity's `RawImage` in your `RawImage` class then provide the namespace to the class name so that Unity will not attempt to use your own version of `RawImage`:

Replace

```
private RawImage UIImageComponent;
UIImageComponent = UIElement.AddComponent(typeof(RawImage)) as RawImage;
```

with:

```
private UnityEngine.UI.RawImage UIImageComponent;
UIImageComponent = UIElement.AddComponent<UnityEngine.UI.RawImage>();
```

---

If your goal is to make your own custom `RawImage` class usable with the `AddComponent` and `GetComponent` function, all you have to do is make it derive from the `MonoBehaviour`. Since your own `RawImage` class derives from another class `UIBaseProperties` which derives from another class `EasyUIData`, you will have to make the final class derive from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class EasyUIData : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected static Canvas EasyCanvasOptions;
    protected static Vector2 EasyCanvasDimensions;
}
```

This should fix your issue since making `EasyUIData` derive from `MonoBehaviour` will make your custom `RawImage` a component that can be attached to a GameObject.

Comment: yeah you are totally right totally missed the fact that i gave them the same name.. Thanks!